# Conectar MySQL Workbench em Servidor Hostinger

Tags: banco-de-dados, conexão, mysql

Várias vezes tentei conectar o **MySQL Workbench** ao banco de dados do meu site hospedado no [hostinger.com.br](http://hostinger.com.br) mas sempre dá erro.

Pelo que entendi os dados de acesso que estou passando são válidos, até por quê são os mesmos usados para conectar a aplicação que estou desenvolvendo em PHP ao banco de dados e funciona.

Mas quando tento conectar ao Banco de dados através do Workbench dá erro. Preciso disso para poder modelar o banco através do Worckbench quando for preciso e apenas dar um Sincronize Model para atualizar as tabelas e não ficar exportando e exportando arquivos .SQL.

Comment: Entre em contado com o suporte do seu servidor. Provavelmente eles só permitem o acesso local (dentro do servidor de aplicação) por questões de segurança.

Comment: Cheguei a imaginar isso também. Vou tentar!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está utilizando a versão gratuita veja essa [questão na base de conhecimento](http://www.hostinger.com.br/base-de-conhecimento/5.html) deles.

> Como acessar o MySQL remotamente:
>
> Infelizmente, não suportamos conexões de MySQL externas em plano
>   gratuito, por questão de segurança e performance.

Comment: Contratei um plano pago e agora consigo conectar. Mas quando executo o comando SHOW DATABASES dá esse erro:

**Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SHOW DATABASES privilege(s) for this operation 0.109 sec**

Comment: @LucianoBraga esse erro já é outro problema e está fora do contexto dessa pergunta. Você não terá acesso de admin a instancia toda do servidor deles, somente ao seus DBs, logo algumas queries seu usuário não terá acesso mesmo.